# Nextjs dynamic page routes: What is the purpose of using the spread operator [...example] or [[...example]] in a page variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js

I am currently learning the `Nextjs` framework. I would say I have a solid grasp of the concepts already, but there are still a few things I am not sure about. One of those things is the spread operator `[...var]` or `[[...var]]` in a dynamic page | route file name.

For example this line from [next/auth docs](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/example):

```
pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js
```

Is there some concrete use case (that can't be achieved using `getStaticPaths()`), or is it just a naming convention which I don't know about?

Comment: this dynamic routing also called dynamic segment which means passing additional parameters through like array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js` is a [catch-all route](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes) which means that it will match `/api/auth/a` but also `/api/auth/a/b`, `/api/auth/a/b/c` and so on.

`[[...nextauth]].js` would be an [optional catch all route](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes). So in addition to the regular catch-all route above it would also match `/api/auth`.

Comment: Ouch, I've completely missed that docs part. Thank you.